# Putting Nodejs onto a website

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework

I have a web app that communicates to a nodejs server. What I am trying to do is allow access to my nodejs server from anywhere not just localhost. Instead of posting to `localhost:8080` in my app I would like to post to my own url like `http://example.com/push` to connect to my nodejs server. Can anyone help me figure this out?

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $http) {
    var isAndroid = ionic.Platform.isAndroid();
    var isios = ionic.Platform.isIOS();
    var fName = $rootScope.fName;
    var lName = $rootScope.lName;
    var messageText = $rootScope.messageText;
    var token = $rootScope.devToken;
    var selectedUser = $rootScope.selectUser;

    $scope.submit = function() {
        $http.post('http://url here', {firstName: fName, lastName: lName, message: messageText, token: token, isAndroid: isAndroid, isios: isios, selectedUser: selectedUser});
        $rootScope.messageText = "";
    }

})
```

---

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    firstName = req.body.firstName;
    lastName = req.body.lastName;
    message = req.body.message;
    token = req.body.token;
    user = {name: firstName + " " + lastName, token: token};
    selectedUser = req.body.selectedUser;
    users.push(user);

    if (req.body.isAndroid === true) {
        sendToAndroid();
    } else {
        sendToios(); 
    }
});



app.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log('running on port 8080');
});
```

Comment: You need to host your app on a domain, you could use [IBM Bluemix](http://www.ibm.com/cloud-computing/bluemix/?S_PKG=AW&cm_mmc=Search_Google-_-IBM+Cloud_IBMCloud_BluemixProgram-_-WW_GB-_-bluemix_Exact_AW&cm_mmca1=000002FP&cm_mmca2=10001882&mkwid=b55ffc68-00ff-461f-bde9-2eebdca5422a%7C401%7C255111&cm_mmc=Search_gsn-_-Cloud_Bluemix_Keyword-Branded_Try-_-WW_US-_-bluemix_Exact) for this

Comment: So if i have my own domain name hosted through go daddy would that not work?

Comment: That would work but you'd have to pay, you can host for free up to certain usage limits on [IBM Bluemix](http://www.ibm.com/cloud-computing/bluemix/?S_PKG=AW&cm_mmc=Search_Google-_-IBM+Cloud_IBMCloud_BluemixProgram-_-WW_GB-_-bluemix_Exact_AW&cm_mmca1=000002FP&cm_mmca2=10001882&mkwid=b55ffc68-00ff-461f-bde9-2eebdca5422a%7C401%7C255111&cm_mmc=Search_gsn-_-Cloud_Bluemix_Keyword-Branded_Try-_-WW_US-_-bluemix_Exact) and [OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/?sc_cid=701600000011p9xAAA&gclid=CL712d7x1c4CFUwW0wod29ABag). There are more options, these are just a couple of examples.

Comment: There is also the option of azure and other such cloud service providers where you could host your server and access from anywhere. They also have source control integration like github for automatic deployment etc.